# Fade text out when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically what I have is a page with a background image and when I have content which is quite long and overflows. I want the text to be inside that image and it appears to fade out when scrolling at the end of the image and the top of the image. I do not want internal scrollbars. The background image itself is fixed and centered and I want the text to always remain inside there.

Is this possible? if this is not clear then I will try and explain myself further.

I have looked at options in Jquery and CSS fading but cannot find exactly what i want.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

H

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you plant an image overlay (white to transparent) at the top and bottom of the div, but that might not work because of your background...could we perhaps see the background you are using?

Comment: @NexxeuS I thought of that but would the solve the problem of the content overflowing? As I said before I do not want internal scrollbars just the main scrollbar on the page.

Comment: If the background and overlay are the same image, it could work. The overlay would fade from 0% to 100% opaque, top to bottom (you'd need to use a PNG).

Comment: You can solve the content overflow problem with overflow:hidden and a fixed height on the container that holds the text..

Comment: @Hem BTW, `overflow:hidden` means that the content will not overflow, `overflow:scroll` means the content will scroll, and `overflow:visible` means the overflowing content will be visible - but no scrollbar.

Comment: @NeXXeuS I just tried out overflow:hidden on some sample html, and it works like I thought, hiding the overflowing content. http://jsfiddle.net/UCbjc/

Comment: @Ishamael The problem with that is there is no ability to scroll and the text gets hidden.

Comment: @Hem I don't think I understand your problem, then. Can you post an image of what you want it to look like?

Comment: Unfortunatley I can't as i'm a new user. I'll try to explain. What you have shown me is correct as it is. Now imagine a bigger version which has text bigger as your example does but it overflows so much that it causes the main scrollbar to appear. I want to be able to scroll using that main scrollbar but the text must remain like the example you have shown. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: And you can't set your height to auto?

Answer (score 0):

The two images Nexxeus says should be placed in a fixed position at the top and bottom of the browser. You shouldn't touch what the overflow does, since it will be hidden below the two images.